# viewbindig class doest instantiate outside onCreate method

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

recommended way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityMainBinding mainView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainView = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(mainView.getRoot());


}
```

}

my way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityMainBinding mainView = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(mainView.getRoot());


}
```

}

in my way i instantiate viewBinding class outside any method in this case outside `onCreate` method, but my app get crush and doesnt open on this way view binding, i just surprised to see it doesnt work, whats wrong with that, as we all know anythings in class body outside any method, all method can access the variable or object properties so on but in my case it seems `setContentView(mainView.getRoot());`

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getLayoutInflater()` too early with regards to activity lifecycle.

Field initialisers run at object instantiation time. `onCreate()` is called much later by the Android framework. At instantiation time the framework has not yet had any chance to initialise anything in the activity object, including system services such as layout inflater.

Comment: i guessed  as idk how actually android instantiate activity, so it seems bit odd thank you